# Relacion muchos a muchos de una tabla consigo misma

Tags: entity-framework-core, modelorelacional

En un trabajo para la universidad me piden modelar los siguientes requerimientos:

- En una aplicacion que se dedicara a la gestion de clientes se desea poder persistir tanto los datos de clientes como de los contactos de los clientes, pero se requiere que el registro se realice en una sola tabla ya que ambas entidades comparten el mismo conjunto de datos.
- Un cliente puede tener muchos contactos y a su vez, un contacto puede ser contacto de muchos clientes.
- Cada contacto que se crea, el sistema lo considerara como un cliente y lo unico que definira su rol como contacto es la relacion con otros clientes.

En conclusion, entiendo que se habla de una entidad persona la cual puede cumplir dos roles: "Cliente" y "Contacto", y que entre ellos existe una relacion muchos a muchos. Mi duda surge de como modelar esto en entity framework core? eh intentado hacerlo con herencia, pero entonces empiezo a tener comportamientos inesperados a causa del discriminator, ya que como se expone en los requerimientos una persona puede ser cliente y contacto al mismo tiempo.

Update:
Es verdad que al enunciado le faltan matices y hasta resulta un poco ambiguo, asi que una aclaracion podria ser que el rol contacto proporciona un canal alternativo de comunicacion con los clientes, y ademas tratare de graficar la propuesta del docente en base al ejemplo recibido en clases:

Imaginemos que se va a registrar un nuevo cliente que dispone de 3 contactos. Diego es el cliente y sus contactos son Juan, Roberto y Andrea.
En esta caso se registran 4 clientes: Diego, Juan, Roberto y Andrea de los cuales los ultimos 3 funcionaran como contactos de Diego (Esto quiere decir que si la empresa no se puede comunicar con Diego, podria intentar cuminicarse con Juan, Roberto o Andrea).

Ahora imaginemos que Andrea decide definir a sus contactos Diego, Ricardo y Susana. En este caso se registrarian dos nuevos clientes: Ricardo y Susana, y se indicarian en la tabla de relacion, como contactos de Andrea, a Diego, Ricardo y Susana.

Comment: ¿Y lo que has intentado es…?

Comment: Estimado, si tienes una respuesta, va en la zona de respuestas, las preguntas se deben quedar como tal. Si te basaste en la respuesta de otro usuario porque su respuesta no llegó a resolver tu escenario, puedes marcarla con un voto a favor (a modo de cortesía) y aceptar la respuesta que tú mismo has resuelto (luego de 24 horas de publicada le das click en el check del costado).

Comment: Recuerda siempre mostrar un [repro] de lo que has intentado, ya que tu pregunta no es netamente teórica (las teóricas son las que no necesitan mostrar código). No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basándome en [la respuesta](/a/610989) de [@Yussef](/users/301324/) e investigando un poco la documentación de entity framework pude llegar a una solución aceptable para el problema planteado:

Primero definí dos entidades:

```cs
public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ClientContact> Clients { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ClientContact> Contacts { get; set; }
    }
public class ClientContact
    {
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        public int ContactId { get; set; }

        public virtual Person Client { get; set; }
        public virtual Person Contact { get; set; }
    }
```

Luego definí sus relaciones en el dbcontext:

```cs
public AppDBContext(DbContextOptions<AppDBContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().ToTable("People");

            modelBuilder.Entity<ClientContact>()
                .HasKey(cc => new {cc.ClientId, cc.ContactId});
            
            modelBuilder.Entity<ClientContact>()
                .HasOne(cc => cc.Client)
                .WithMany(cc => cc.Contacts)
                .HasForeignKey(cc => cc.ClientId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
            
            modelBuilder.Entity<ClientContact>()
                .HasOne(cc => cc.Contact)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(cc => cc.ContactId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        }

        public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    }
```

Con esta configuración pude crear nuevas entradas de esta manera:

```cs
Person cliente = new Person
{
    Name = "Diego"
};

Person contacto1 = new Person
{
    Name = "Juan"
};

Person contacto2 = new Person
{
    Name = "Roberto"
};

//asociar los clientes y los contactos:
cliente.Contacts = new List<ClientContact>
{
    new ClientContact { Client = cliente, Contact = contacto1 },
    new ClientContact { Client = cliente, Contact = contacto2 }
};
```

Y finalmente enviar los cambios a la BD:

```cs
dbContext.People.Add(cliente);
dbContext.People.Add(contacto1);
dbContext.People.Add(contacto2);

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Nada que agradecer estimado, viendo tu respuesta me parece que debería funcionar como tu esperas. Solo te aconsejo darle otra vuelta a mi respuesta, porque me parece que no es necesario crear una clase `ClientContact`,  que funcionalmente es lo mismo pero lo hace mas complejo. Fíjate que en mi respuesta yo no hago uso de esa Clase y aun así EF crea esa tabla, y aun sin esa clase puedo fácilmente relacionar Clientes con contactos y contactos con clientes. Saludos

Comment: Esta respuesta no tiene mucho sentido.. funciona?? si.. pero tiene errores de concepto... No deberias usar ICollection para nada.  Todas las referencias, deberian ser por ID, no por nombre... Tener en una clase.. La clase ClientContact no tiene ningun sentido. Bastaba con aceptar la respuesta que te dieron, que funciona, y no agrear otra, que funciona, pero con errores conceptuales...

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario @gbianchi, pero yo implemento el CONCEPTO de  solución que a mi me parezca, ya que lo que pedi fue un modelo y no una solucion concreta.

Comment: Aqui no damos modelos.. damos soluciones a problemas concretos... yo te explique solamente porque vote negativa tu solucion, porque aunque arregla el problema, tiene errores de concepto...

Comment: 1- No sabia que la comunidad de SOes era tan quisquillosa con estos temas. Imaginaba una comunidad un poco mas amigable.
2- Puedes darle todos los negativos que te parezcan, no vine a buscar ningún tipo de reputación ni reconocimiento.
3- Después de leer todo lo que leí, con excepción de las respuestas de Yussef y David, que aportaban valor al post, la verdad es que me dan pocas ganas de seguir participando en esta comunidad.

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero es que esto no es posible de hacer con una UNA sola tabla, requieres al menos 2 para hacer la relación muchos a muchos consigo misma. No obstante si es posible usando una sola clase.

Además dices que:

> En conclusion, entiendo que se habla de una entidad persona la cual
> puede cumplir dos roles: "Cliente" y "Contacto", y que entre ellos
> existe una relacion muchos a muchos.

No es así, solo existe la entidad `Cliente`, todos son clientes. Y serán contactos solo en relación a sus clientes.
No necesitas crear una clase `Persona` y heredar de ella

Un ejemplo, digamos que tenemos 5 personas: Juan, Diego, Jose, Alvaro y Gonzalo; y definimos que:

- Juan tiene como contactos a Diego y Jose
- Alvaro tiene como contactos a Jose y Gonzalo
- Gonzalo tiene como contactos a Diego

Al definir lo anterior, estamos provocando automáticamente estas otras relaciones:

- Juan no es cliente de nadie
- Diego es cliente de Juan y Gonzalo
- Jose es cliente de Juan y Alvaro
- Alvaro tampoco tiene clientes
- Gonzalo es cliente de Alvaro

<sub>Nota mental: Es más difícil la explicación que la implementación</sub>

Para esto tu clase te queda simplemente así:

```
public class Cliente
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    //otras propiedades como edad, dirección, etc

    public List<Cliente> ClienteDe { get; set; } = new();
    public List<Cliente> Contactos { get; set; } = new();
}
```

Básicamente las 2 ultimas listas provocan la relación muchos a muchos contra la misma entidad y así de simple. Siendo `ClienteDe` la lista de quienes es cliente la entidad y `Contactos`  la lista de contactos que posee la entidad.

Luego para implementar esto necesitas una Base de Datos, yo por ejemplo usaré `SQLite` y crear el respectivo `DbContext`, el cual solo implementa el `DbSet<Cliente> Clientes`, no hay que agregar nada mas

Ejemplo de `DbContext`

```js
public partial class Context : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Cliente> Clientes { get; set; }
    public Context()
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    public Context(DbContextOptions<Context> options) : base(options)
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
        
    
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }

    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}
```

Y luego probamos con los datos del ejemplo:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
       
    var opt = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<Context>().UseSqlite($"Data Source={System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}/datos.db").Options;
    var db = new Context(opt);

    Cliente juan = new() { Name = "Juan" };
    Cliente diego = new() { Name = "Diego" };
    Cliente jose = new() { Name = "Jose" };
    Cliente alvaro = new() { Name = "Alvaro" };
    Cliente gonzalo = new() { Name = "Gonzalo" };
            
    juan.Contactos.Add(diego);
    juan.Contactos.Add(jose);

    alvaro.Contactos.Add(jose);
    alvaro.Contactos.Add(gonzalo);

    gonzalo.Contactos.Add(diego);

          

    db.Clientes.AddRange([juan, diego, jose, alvaro, gonzalo]);
    db.SaveChanges();

    foreach (var item in db.Clientes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Name + " sus contactos son: " + string.Join(",", item.Contactos.Select(a=>a.Name)));
        Console.WriteLine(item.Name + " es cliente de: " + string.Join(",", item.ClienteDe.Select(a => a.Name)));
        Console.WriteLine("=============================================");
    }
       
}
```

Notar que solo seteamos los "Contactos", EF es lo suficientemente inteligente para inferir que se trata de una relación muchos a muchos y setea las lista `ClienteDe` por nosotros (la misma inferencia que hicimos al inicio: Si X es contacto de Y, Y será cliente X).

El ejemplo anterior imprime

```
Juan sus contactos son: Diego,Jose
Juan es cliente de:
=============================================
Diego sus contactos son:
Diego es cliente de: Juan,Gonzalo
=============================================
Jose sus contactos son:
Jose es cliente de: Juan,Alvaro
=============================================
Alvaro sus contactos son: Jose,Gonzalo
Alvaro es cliente de:
=============================================
Gonzalo sus contactos son: Diego
Gonzalo es cliente de: Alvaro
=============================================
```

Yo usé `code first`, es decir creé la clase y EF generó las tablas por mi, y tal como te decía al principio se generan 2 tablas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor evitar charlar en los comentarios.

Comment: "EF es lo suficientemente inteligente" falacias no por favor.. jajajajaj

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo modelaría tal y como indicas, pero añadiendo las relaciones `es_contacto` y `es_cliente` vinculadas con la misma entidad `personas`:

[image: Modelo ER]

Debes tener en cuenta que ser contacto y ser cliente son dos relaciones independientes. Bueno, tal vez para ser cliente antes debes ser contacto, pero también se puede entender que puedes dejar de ser contacto pero no por ello dejarás de ser cliente, en el sentido histórico del término (por el hecho de haberte comprado algo, alguien ya ha sido tu cliente de por vida). O eso, o te haces una abstracción con `es_contacto` y `personas` para repetir la misma jugada con `es_cliente`. Pero creo que sería complicar el modelo innecesariamente, cuando de forma independiente ya tiene suficiente miga. Por otra parte, si alguien ha sido tu cliente, pero ha dejado de ser tu contacto, significaría que ya no será más tu cliente, así que la semántica sigue siendo funcional.

Por otra parte, al enunciado de tu problema le faltan matices que debes preguntar al cliente/profesor. Si presupones que todas las personas son clientes, ¿cómo piensas modelar quién es el proveedor/comercial de cada cliente de la empresa? No tiene sentido que un cliente sea el proveedor de otro, así que tendrás que registrar también a los comerciales, vendedores o proveedores que les prestarán el servicio y con los que estarán en contacto. Ésta es la complicación de inventarse enunciados teóricos, que llegas a este tipo de callejones sin salida. Siempre es preferible modelar casos reales, que pueden llegar a complicarse bastante más que los teóricos, pero al menos siempre hay respuesta para estas dudas de diseño que van surgiendo. Por lo tanto, mi sugerencia es eliminar del enunciado esa restricción de que todas las personas sean clientes y dejar que las personas sigan siendo personas para que puedan ser tanto clientes como proveedores, obteniendo su rol definitivo en la relación `es_cliente`.

Espero haberte ayudado, si tienes dudas, por favor déjamelas en los comentarios.

Comment: Esta pidiendo la solucion en ef_core... esta respuesta no lo explica asi...

Comment: @gbianchi Un placer saludarte. El OP no parece tener dificultades con el EF Core, sino con el modelado de su problema, el cual debería ser independiente de la tecnología en la que finalmente se implemente.

Comment: sacado textual de la pregunta "Mi duda surge de como modelar esto en entity framework core? "